# Solve problem of ages in different time periods analytically

Tags: soft-question

I've struggled to solve the following problem analytically:

> Ann is $24$ and two times as old as Mary was, when Ann was as old as Mary is now.

The solution to this problem is:

> Mary is currently 18 years old.

but I've failed to come up with an analytical way to conclude this. Any ideas?

**This is what I've tried:**

$$
y_{\text{Ann}} = 24 \;\,\,\text{and}\,\,\; y_{\text{Ann}} = 2 \cdot y_{\text{Mary (at the time Ann was as old Mary is now)}} \\
\Rightarrow \;\;\;\;12 = y_{\text{Mary (at the time Ann was as old Mary is now)}}
$$

at this point I got stuck..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A,M$ denote their current ages and let $C$ denote the number of years that have elapsed since the prior time under discussion.  That is, $C$ is the difference between their two ages.

Then:  $$A=24\quad \quad A-C=M\quad \quad A = 2\times (M-C)$$

It is easy to solve this system to get $M=18$.

Comment: Thank you really much for the time. Nice solution ^^